# "I disagree with those people" is a bad answer

Tags: discussion, answers, best-practice

We have had many answers that follow this pattern (using the unicorn theme from the [about](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/about) page):

> Q: Some people say that your unicorn's horn should be buffed gently with chamois in order to bring out the opalescent shimmer. Do they recommend this for all unicorns, or only those with rainbow manes?
>
> A: *True* unicorn lovers would know you never polish the horn. Those people are just wrong.

This is not a good answer. A question which requests answers *from a particular faith tradition* needs to be answered from that perspective - it's not correct to answer by denying the validity of the subject matter. (I'm not talking about questions that contain blatant factual errors, or have other problems: this is about good, targeted questions.)

Unfortunately, there are some contentious topics where we are having trouble with this - including such bugbears as homosexuality, evolution, the interpretation of the Bible, veneration of the saints, what happens at communion, and so on. We are doing a reasonable job (I think) in moderating such answers, but I wanted to write this meta post because:

1. It is a continuing problem, and
2. Moderation has been a bit uneven: we should be vigilant for this pattern in general, not just when it is our own tradition being attacked.

There is no new policy here but I did want to take this opportunity to sum up some existing guidelines. For a question from the perspective of Tradition X, the following answer patterns are *never* acceptable:

- Followers of X are deluded / disregard the Bible / have been misled by Satan / have succumbed to modern liberal tendencies / are stuck in the Dark Ages / are just plain stupid / lack faith / ...
- Not-X is the correct position because ...
- Many people in the past who believed X were indescribably evil monsters, who used to only *pretend* to throw the ball for their dog, and were actually holding it *all along*. Do you *really* want to be like them?
- "He who does X is justly condemned; accursed indeed is the X-er." - The Bible

Please don't write answers like that, and do use the various community moderation tools (commenting, editing, voting, flagging, etc.) as appropriate.

Comment: I would like to ask for specific examples because I do not think I see this happening too often, and when it does, those answers are usually downvoted pretty quickly.

Comment: You raise good points, but -1's are probably the best recourse.